# sendmail still send via estmp when I configured relay system

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to config `sendmail` to relay mail through external smtp server:

**`sendmail.mc`**

```
include(`/etc/mail/m4/dialup.m4')dnl
include(`/etc/mail/m4/provider.m4')dnl
dnl # 
dnl # Default Mailer setup
define('SMART_HOST','212.227.15.142')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo')dnl 
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl
```

Authinfo file

```
AuthInfo:212.227.15.142 "U:myuser@mydomain.es" "I:myuser@mydomain.es" "P:*********" "M:LOGIN PLAIN"
```

After each change I do this:

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
makemap hash authinfo < authinfo
make
```

All commands are executed without problems.

But when I send a mail using `mail()` php function in `var/log/mail.log` I got:

(I try to send to `****@gmx.com` mail address)

```
Jul  6 09:05:06 ubuntu sendmail[63599]: w667561E063599: to=*****@gmx.com, ctladdr=********@mydomain.es (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30208, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w66756Vp063600 Message accepted for delivery)
Jul  6 09:05:06 ubuntu sm-mta[63602]: w66756Vp063600: to=<*****@gmx.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120544, relay=mx01.gmx.net. [212.227.17.4], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by mx01.gmx.net.
```

I think that sendmail does not read the smtp credentials or something (ip `212.227.15.142` (smarthost) is not on the log).

**UPDATE**

When I try:

```
sendmail -v -s "test" rj1000@gmail.com
```

I obtain this, thus I don't see any trace of my smtp authentication or smarthost ip.

```
rj1000@gmail.com,test... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 localhost.localdomain ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3; Mon, 9 Jul 2018 17:10:23 +0200; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
250-localhost.localdomain Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<root@localhost.localdomain> AUTH=root@localhost.localdomain
250 2.1.0 <root@localhost.localdomain>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<rj1000@gmail.com>
>>> RCPT To:<test@localhost.localdomain>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <rj1000@gmail.com>... Recipient ok
550 5.1.1 <test@localhost.localdomain>... User unknown
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <rj1000@gmail.com>... Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
050 220 mx.google.com ESMTP j25-v6si9299388wme.67 - gsmtp
050 >>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
050 250-mx.google.com at your service, [212.145.243.67]
050 250-SIZE 157286400
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-STARTTLS
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250-PIPELINING
050 250-CHUNKING
050 250 SMTPUTF8
050 >>> STARTTLS
050 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
050 >>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
050 250-mx.google.com at your service, [212.145.243.67]
050 250-SIZE 157286400
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250-PIPELINING
050 250-CHUNKING
050 250 SMTPUTF8
050 >>> MAIL From:<root@localhost.localdomain> SIZE=274
050 250 2.1.0 OK j25-v6si9299388wme.67 - gsmtp
050 >>> RCPT To:<rj1000@gmail.com>
050 >>> DATA
050 250 2.1.5 OK j25-v6si9299388wme.67 - gsmtp
050 354  Go ahead j25-v6si9299388wme.67 - gsmtp
050 >>> .
050 250 2.0.0 OK 1531149023 j25-v6si9299388wme.67 - gsmtp
050 <rj1000@gmail.com>... Sent (OK 1531149023 j25-v6si9299388wme.67 - gsmtp)
250 2.0.0 w69FANdO004647 Message accepted for delivery
rj1000@gmail.com... Sent (w69FANdO004647 Message accepted for delivery)
>>> RSET
250 2.0.0 Reset state
root... Using cached ESMTP connection to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
>>> MAIL From:<> SIZE=1024
250 2.1.0 <>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<root@localhost.localdomain>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <root@localhost.localdomain>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <root@localhost.localdomain>... Connecting to local...
050 <root@localhost.localdomain>... Sent
250 2.0.0 w69FANdQ004647 Message accepted for delivery
root... Sent (w69FANdQ004647 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 localhost.localdomain closing connection
```

I suppose that the log must indicate "via relay" and not "via esmtp", something is wrong in my config.

**EDIT 2**

For any reason, I have to modify sendmail.cf directly, because sendmail.mc modification and the next "make" action. Now smarthost is working.

Comment: Did you restart sendmail?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, I did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that sendmail.cf was not update from make command. I recommend check the sendmail.cf content or directly modify it. With this command I finally to achieve to create a valid cf file from mc:

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```

Answer (score 0):

The log indicates **relay=mx01.gmx.net.**

Jul  6 09:05:06 ubuntu sm-mta[63602]: w66756Vp063600: to=<*****@gmx.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120544, **relay=mx01.gmx.net.** [212.227.17.4], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by mx01.gmx.net.

It's trying to relay but the SMTP server running on *mx01.gmx.net* does not accept relaying

```
Connection refused by mx01.gmx.net.
```

Just configure mx01.gmx.net to allow relay from your MTA.

Comment: No. mx01.gmx.net has not the ip that i indicated in smarthost (212.227.15.142).